# What is this blue mesh tube thing in the Rema TT 06 patch kit used for?

Tags: repair, tools, co2

I own an (old-ish) Rema TT 06 patch kit. The contents look like this:

[image: patch kit]

Notice the blue tube-like thing under the left box. In the part list on the manufacturer's site, I couldn't find any mention of that thing (http://www.rematiptop.com/part.php?pid=56&cid=5&sid=4, which is also the source of the image).

Is is basically a short tube of mesh-like, flexible material. What is it used for?

Comment: If desired, I can take a picture of the thing and post it tomorrow :-)

Comment: You say its oldish - this means the patches and vulcanising fluid may be beyond their useby date.  All the other items will be okay for decades, excluding water/sweat damage.

Comment: @Criggie "oldish" in this case means 10 years or older. The fluid has been used up for quite some time, but with one of the patches I had trouble fixing a tube. That was about a year ago, so you are probably right. Thanks for the hint :-) (The question occurred to me when I was looking at the kit to see which stuff was still useable.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at manufacturers site I found [repair kit](https://kis.rema-tiptop.net/catalog/RTT/CatalogArticleDetails.aspx?LanguageID=EN&L=6&LL=&GLS0=1&GLS1=8&GLS2=2&GLS3=6&PLS0=1&API0=5060351) with 'mysterious' blue mesh listed as "Cartridge freeze protector".

It is supposed to be put over the cartridge (like in this picture) to prevent skin irritation/burn because CO2 gets very cold when discharged.

[image: CO2 cartridge with freeze protector]

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that option! I thought it was a part like a patch that would be used (up) by the repair, not a tool simply used to repair the tube. Interesting that the manufacturer doesn't list the freeze protector in the parts list of the bike repair kit.

Comment: @anderas might have been a later addition that was initially thought to be unnecessary.  The paper packaging could have been printed up before the extra part was added.